Activity is re-created on removing health connect access permission
Device details:
OS version: 14
Device: Samsung S23 FE
Issue:
I'm developing an app, where I'm using health connect to read weight data. 
I have allowed read weight data access to my app

When I'm on Activity A, I background the app and remove all access from health connect
Then when I foreground the app
Process ends and is re-started and Activity is recreated
Why does this happen? Are there any callbacks we receive on removing access in health connect? Or are there any other intent that need to be added to handle this?

Currently, I'm using below lines:


How to suppress restarting of the activity?

where are the lines you mentioned?

This behavior follows the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#app_process_terminates_when_permission_revoked

@Laser
Below are the permission intents added:



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is standard in Android for any permission revocation.  There's no callback.  But Activity recreation is common on Android anyway (it happens if they so much as tilt the phone to landscape), so your app should be architected to handle it.
